# Resources for learning LINQ?

Tags: linq, linq-to-sql, linq-to-entities, asp.net-3.5

I'm looking to learn LINQ, but I'm finding that there is a lot more to it then what I initally expected. In fact, there's so much that I'm not sure where is the best place to start. I know that there's LINQ to SQL, and LINQ to Entities, and a number of other LINQ whatevers out there.

Which is the best to start with? It seems that I see more information readily available about LINQ to SQL, but I have seen quite a bit of information about LINQ to Entities also. Is LINQ to Entities more difficult than LINQ to SQL?

Also, I'm looking for some good resources on learning LINQ. I've seen that Scott Gu has a few blogs on LINQ to SQL, but I'm looking for a little more. Does anyone have a LINQ book that they're impressed with?

Comment: Thanks to all who gave me resources on this!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the beginning, I found [Standard Query Operators](http://download.microsoft.com/download/5/8/6/5868081c-68aa-40de-9a45-a3803d8134b8/standard_query_operators.doc) (MS Word .doc) an invaluable reference.

Pro LINQ by Joseph Rattz is a great book on the subject, although it doesn't cover LINQ to Entities.

As well as in depth examples for each of the standard query operators, it covers:

- LINQ to Objects
- LINQ to XML
- LINQ to DataSet
- LINQ to SQL

Comment: Very useful. I'll keep it hanging around for a quick reference when I'm stumped on those LINQ questies. Thanks.

Answer (score 27):

LINQ Pad is a good way to start learning, its also free...

http://www.linqpad.net/

Comment: +1 this has become an essential tool for me. I use it every day.

Comment: [OzCode](http://www.oz-code.com) now offers a way of learning LINQ that actually visualizes how each item passed through the LINQ pipeline, giving somewhat deeper insight than LINQPad does. Check out [A Visual Lexicon of LINQ](https://www.simple-talk.com/dotnet/net-development/visual-lexicon-linq/) for some examples.

Answer (score 6):

I have been looking quite alot for the same, but i have found that there isnt really a place where everything is together..

But there is a few good resources.

LinQ 101 - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vcsharp/aa336746.aspx

And this one got quite a few small example snippets on how to do things in alot of different languages.
And it got a section for linq too

http://www.java2s.com/Code/CSharp/LINQ/CatalogLINQ.htm

Id say start with linq to sql, they stopped developing that a while back, but the syntax is exactly like linq to entities, linq to entities and linq to sql is almost the same, there is a few things different, but id say start from the "bottom" :)

This is a really good tutorial about how to jump from "linq to sql" to "linq to entities"
http://naspinski.net/post/Getting-started-with-Linq-To-Entities.aspx

Comment: I'd read that MS was done with LINQ to SQL, but then I ran into other stuff that suggested it wasn't going away because the community likes it so much.

Answer (score 2):

Although this isn't free, and might seem "daunting" to a beginner.  But the Professional LINQ book published by Wrox I found was good as a "get your feet wet" book.  It's not what I would consider part of their professional series despite the title and doesn't go into nearly as much depth as it should, but it's a good start nevertheless.

Answer (score 2):

This book/ebook is very good also. Very good for starters.
http://www.manning.com/marguerie/

Answer (score 2):

[Here](http://www.pmakesp.com/Topic/TakeQuiz/Language%20Integrated%20Query%2c%20in%20C%23/758)'s a great site for practicing it (and also c#).
It still doesn't have LOTS of questions, but there are just enough to get you going (and you can also add questions yourself).

Answer (score 1):

The next best thing to a personal beginner LINQ tutor:

http://www.asp.net/LEARN/linq-videos/

Answer (score 0):

Another good way to learn LINQ is by browsing through code examples, and try them out on your own, if time permits.

Here are two of my personal favorite LINQ resources, which both have easy to understand code examples, and in my view are great for the beginner:

http://linqsamples.com

and

http://www.dotnetperls.com/linq