# Where is a good place to start learning LINQ

Tags: .net, linq

Where is a good place to start learning LINQ for .net, and what are the resources i should use to put the knowledge into practice?

Comment: You might want to check out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16322/learning-about-linq -- not really a duplicate, but it already provides some possible answers to this question.

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/830581/resources-for-learning-linq

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think the [MSDN LINQ samples](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vcsharp/aa336746.aspx) are an excellent place to start.  Just start going through the first couple examples under each topic, and you'll soon get the gist.

Answer (score 3):

In terms of resources [LINQPad](http://www.linqpad.net/) is quite handy. Plus a few [video tutorials](http://windowsclient.net/learn/videos_LINQ.aspx) here should be useful too.

cheers

Answer (score 3):

[LINQPad](http://www.linqpad.net/) to practice your queries.

Answer (score 0):

You can try out [MSDN - Linq 101](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/101-LINQ-Samples-3fb9811b)