# How to configure c# Web Browser Search dialog behavior?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, browser

I have a very large HTML file that I want to search in (using the web browser control from VS 2010).  Is there a way to configure the search box (CTRL-F) to *not* search incrementally?  That is, if I try to type in the word "handbook", the control seems to begin scanning the entire document for every letter 'h', than every instance of 'ha' - which is great for short documents, but for very large (mine is about 35MB), it makes the search useless - and no, I cannot get the document vendor to produce many smaller documents - that is a non-starter :-)

Answer (score 0):

Try cutting and pasting your search text into the search input rather than typing it.

Comment: Is it possible to launch the built-in "Find" dialog ALONG with the desired search text?

Answer (score 0):

first use threads to call search method. then use `Thread.Sleep(/*the number*/);` in search method to wait for user to write the correct search pattern. then get the `TextBox.Text`(Serach Pattern)

this is sample Code:

at first:

```
using System.Threading;
```

Form1 Constructor:

```
public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        Form1.CheckForIllegalCrossThreadCalls = false;
        //another codes that you want

    }
```

TextBox TextChanged Event:

```
private void textBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Thread t=new Thread(SearchMethod);
    t.Start();    
}
```

The SearchMethod:

```
private SearchMethod()
{
    Thread.Sleep(5000); //wait 5 second in this state form doesn't hang. 
    Search(TextBox.Text);
}
```

search:

```
private Search(string pattern)
{
    //Do search
}
```

Comment: I'm looking to use the built-in search (because of the highlighting within an HTML document) - if feasible.

Comment: @SC28: and isn't it possible with my answer?

Comment: Sure, if I replace the built-in search dialog - your approach will work, just becomes a larger project when you need to highlight the text within the original html document and provide next/previous document navigation.

Comment: @SC28: Did you see my another answer?

Answer (score 0):

It's another ways. for your huge string you can use LINQ to find data. It's faster than another ways. you should use Google to learn LINQ but [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/830581/resources-for-learning-linq) can help you to start with LINQ

Comment: Thanks - stuck with .Net 2.0 :-( for this project.

Comment: @SC28 Why you don't use .Net 3.5?!

Answer (score 0):

I think you may have problem because of the windows IE version. Because the web browser uses IE to render (and maybe search) the page.

and You also can use htmlagilitypack (I think it can be useful)